# Cant fetch a DOM element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been reading about the different `getlementbyID`, `name` etc but I'm stuck with a problem. My DOM tree looks like this:

```
<suggestion>
    <term>Some text here</term>
    <term changed="true"> Some text here </term>
</suggestion>
```

I am trying to get the tagname term `changed="true"` but when I try with `getElementsByTagName` it does not work. I have also tried with `querySelectorAll("term changed=true")` but it still doesn't work.

Sometimes there might be more than one `<term>` so I am not trying to fetch the 2nd element, sometimes it might be 3rd, 4th or 9th element...

How can I fetch specifically this element, and not the other elements that are just `<term>`?

Comment: What specifically have you tried with 'querySelectorAll'?

Comment: querySelectorAll("term changed=true");

It doesnt return anything, but when I look in the console, its suppose to return..

Comment: `getlementbyID` isnt the same as `getElementbyId`

Comment: Based on your comment, it looks like you have the query selector formatted wrong.  See @TKoL's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you were trying to find the `term=true` with the wrong selector. I have it working just fine, I think:

https://jsfiddle.net/wdtyore1/1/

`var element = document.querySelector('term[changed="true"]');`

Comment: This is the explanation i was looking for, i dont understand why you need to use brackets, but this solved my problem and is working perfectly!

Comment: 'querySelector' is just CSS selectors. a space between strings indicates you're talking about an element *inside* the element previously selected, so `term changed` would look for a `changed` element inside a `term` element. Brackets is how you select for element with specific properties or property values

Comment: @PlayPhil1 i'm glad your thing is working perfectly. Please mark an answer as correct if you feel it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just because this is not part of the HTML5 spec, doesn't mean that it isn't accessible via JS

For your specific example this will get you the value of changed:
`document.getElementsByTagName('term')[1].getAttribute("changed")`

Note that `document.getElementsByTagName('term')` returns an array, so you likely want to have a loop that looks through this array.

Also if you are using jQuery, you could always looks for something like this:
`$('term[changed]').attr('changed')`